# Will Integrated Windows Authentication ever fall back to plain text username & password?

Tags: security, windows-authentication

I'm trying to learn more about Integrated Windows Authentication but everything I read introduces me to three new acronyms, many of which incorporate other acronyms, and I don't feel I know anything about the mechanics.

I understand that if an HTTP client doesn't support Integrated Windows Authentication there is a chain of fallbacks that can identify the client and might involve prompting for a username and password. Is there ever a case where it will fallback to HTTP Basic Authentication or any other plain text username / password communication?

I'm trying to determine if I need to provide SSL to protect user credentials and I'm hoping that all authentication is secured in some way.

Comment: I am trying to remember the answer to your question and failing. I think it is no but I can't be sure yet. I'll think about it some more.

That said, you probably need SSL anyway to avoid other attacks, even if it is just tokens that you're passing back and forth. Or at least a signed stream (at which point most people just do SSL anyway).

Comment: @EricFleischman thanks for your input. This is for an internal network with non-sensitive data, so I'm actually not too worried about any kind of attack. However I have to ensure passwords are protected to satisfy corporate policy

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on that. Most attacks come from internal networks.

Comment: @EricFleischman fair enough, although in this case it's my opinion - and more importantly my client's opinion - that the value of attacking this particular system is not worth the risk of being caught, fired, and sued for breach of policy. All network users are allowed to view the data. Edits are restricted but there's no personal gain beyond entertainment for manipulating data. Corporate policy forces us to look at this specific problem but the policy is based on much more sensitive systems

Comment: @EricFleischman do you have any references to support the statement that most attacks come from internal networks?

Comment: I don't. It is my observation as a practitioner of the art over the past bunch of years. More attack come from bad guy attacking other system and hopping to impt system than come from bad guy attacking critical system. This is my observation and belief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no plain-text credential for the SSPs available to IWA in a default installation (NTLM and Kerberos). In principle you could deploy some other SSP and make it available to IWA via NegoEx, and that SSP might implement password checking in the clear, but that's pretty unlikely.

Of course there is nothing stopping a web application from returning a response requesting HTTP Basic Authentication or Forms Authentication, independently of IWA, so you would have to check no applications were doing that.

> I'm trying to determine if I need to provide SSL to protect user credentials and I'm hoping that all authentication is secured in some way.

If you're only interested in complying with a corporate policy against cleartext passwords, then IWA should be enough.

If you have a real threat model and it includes a snooper on the network, then you have much more to worry about - such an attacker can just as easily do active man-in-the-middle attacks and make the web application appear to do something like create a bogus NTLM login box that leaks passwords. That's why you might want SSL.